# How to make calculations with specific lines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have basic to medium knowledge in Excel, and I am having trouble with a somewhat complicated problem for me.

I have a table where I need to relate three columns: a "Type" column, and another two with numeric values, which I need to divide by one.

The problem is: I would like to perform this calculation only for rows that have a certain "Type", and then average the results. Something like the image linked below.

I know more or less how logic should work. I tried using the "Format as Table" function and using the "IF" function with the column name, something like IF (Sheet1 [Type] = "A"; Sheet1 [Data 2] / Sheet1 [Data 1]; "NA "), but I think that's not how it works.

I also tried the VLOOKUP function, but I couldn't think straight out how I could average the values later.

Thank you for your help.

[The result would be something like this, but for a very large table it would be impracticable to do so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBwCk.png)
[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: Please include your expected result as per your sample data. Also include your own attempt at least.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer: Without any helper column: `=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$12=E2)*(C$2:C$12/B$2:B$12))/COUNTIF(A$2:A$12;E2)` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could create an auxiliary column with `Data 2`/`Data 1`, then use this column to calculate the average using something like:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A100,"A",D2:D100)/COUNTIF(A2:A100,"A")
```

Where

- Column A is the `Type` (Contains "A" or "B")
- Column B is `Data 1`
- Column C is `Data 2`
- Column D is the auxiliary column (`Data 2`/`Data 1`)

[image: Example Screenshot]

I don't think you can go straight with a formula to the result without the auxiliary calculated column.

I hope it helps.

---

As suggested by máté-juhász, `AVERAGEIF` is a much better way:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A100,"A",D2:D100)
```

Comment: Why not use AVERAGEIF?

Comment: OK. I was thinking in a much more complicated way than I needed.

Using the AVERAGEIF function like this was exactly what I couldn't think of.

Thank you for helping!